# THREEjs - Convert font to typeface.json

Tags: fonts, three.js, typeface

I am trying to convert few fonts (`.ttf`) into `typeface.json`. Looking around I found this webpage [Facetype.js](https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/) however, when I hit convert nothing happens. I have tested it in all browser and even downloaded the standalone from github.

Any other converter around?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? If there's a problem in the converter you could help them find it and solve it.

Comment: I have checked it but no errors are shown

Comment: It's possible that it only supports OpenType TTF files. Are you uploading those or TrueType?

Comment: I am uploading ttf files

Comment: did someone tried it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload the web page. because Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.